# How do I load a popover from a view controller in storyboard programatically.

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, popover

I'm loading a popover from a collection view cell when the user taps on a button. I have managed to get the popover to work but I dont know how to load a view controller that I set up  in storyboards.

Here is the code that gets me a popover. How can I get it to load a view controller from the storyboard?

```
self.popoverContent = [[PopOverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UpcomingCells" bundle:nil];


UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];


[popoverView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:224/256.0 green:45/256.0 blue:117/256.0 alpha:1.0]];



self.popoverContent.view = popoverView;

self.popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 300);

self.contactPopover =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.popoverContent];

[self.contactPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.remindButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES ];

[self.contactPopover setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are pretty clear on this, you should use

`-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html

So assuming that you need to load your viewController into self.popOverContent, you do

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"nameOfStoryboard" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
self.popoverContent = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nameOfViewController"];
```

Just replace nameOfViewController and nameOfStoryboard with actual names ;)

EDIT:
the storyboard name is just the name of your stoyboard-file, minus the extension.
so for "myStoryboard.storyboard" you would simply use "myStoryboard".
Also you need to set a stoyboard-Identifier for your viewController. Its called stryboard-id, and its right below where you set the class name for your viewController, in the identity-inspector.

Comment: SInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x75df8a0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'PopOverViewController''. I'm not sure how to set name of view controller and I'm assuming name of storyboard is the storyboard filename.

Comment: Thanks so much. Saved me so much time have to program the buttons programatically.

Comment: Just to note the call is storyboardWithName:bundle: - note the lowercase storyboard and the added bundle: parameter